# C# WCF Exception occurs when returning list type as object

Tags: c#, wcf

```
--- SERVER
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "TEST")]
public interface IServer
{
    [OperationContract]        
    object test();
}


[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
class ServerWCallbackImpl : IServer
{
    public object test()
    {
        List<bool> data = new List<bool>();
        data.Add(false);
        data.Add(true);
        data.Add(false);
        return data;
    }
}

---- CLIENT
DuplexChannelFactory<IServer> cf =
            new DuplexChannelFactory<IServer>(  new CallbackImpl(), new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8080/TEST"));
        IContractServerAgent srv = cf.CreateChannel();
        List<bool> data = srv.test() as List<bool>;


-----------------------
```

Returning a variable such as int or bool is not a problem.

Returning list type throws an Exception.

Exception occure : the server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your method test should return type of List instead  of object,

```
public List<bool> test()
    {
        List<bool> data = new List<bool>();
        data.Add(false);
        data.Add(true);
        data.Add(false);
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Can I return list as object type?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the server doesn't know how to serialize an `object` - it could quite literally be anything.

As other answers have said, you need to return it as a `List<bool>` so that it can be serialized (turned into json/xml) and sent to the client

Answer (score 1):

> WCF needs to know what type are you passing so that it can deserialise that object in other words **WCF is strongly typed** framework.

[C# WCF Passing Dictionary<string, object> parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621002/c-sharp-wcf-passing-dictionarystring-object-parameter/42623176#42623176)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return an object then consider using `Stream` like this:

```
public Stream test()
{
    List<bool> data = new List<bool>();
    data.Add(false);
    data.Add(true);
    data.Add(false);
    return MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
}
```

or simply return `List<bool>`